# How to split a numeric field into smaller segments in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, split, group-by, tile

I have a table in SQL Server with two fields.

```
Total      Group
35645      24
12400      55
30000      41
```

I want to split each group into smaller segments of fixed size 7000, with the remainder of each group into the last segment. So, the output should look like below.

```
Segment  Total     Group
1        7000       24
2        7000       24
3        7000       24
4        7000       24
5        7000       24
6        645        24
1        7000       55
2        5400       55
1        7000       41
2        7000       41
3        7000       41
4        7000       41
5        2000       41
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it:

```
declare @t table (Total int,[Group] int)
insert into @t(Total,[Group]) values
(35645,24 ),
(12400,55 ),
(30000,41 )
;With Numbers as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number)-1 n
    from master..spt_values
)
select
    n.n+1 as Segment,
    CASE WHEN (n.n+1)*7000 < t.Total THEN 7000
    ELSE t.Total - (n.n*7000) END as Total,
    t.[Group]
from
    @t t inner join
    Numbers n on n.n*7000 < t.Total
```

(If you already have a `Numbers` table you can eliminate that part. I'm using `spt_values` just as a table that I know has plenty of rows in it, so that the `ROW_NUMBER()` expression should generate all of the necessary numbers)

Results:

```
Segment              Total                Group
-------------------- -------------------- -----------
1                    7000                 24
2                    7000                 24
3                    7000                 24
4                    7000                 24
5                    7000                 24
6                    645                  24
1                    7000                 55
2                    5400                 55
1                    7000                 41
2                    7000                 41
3                    7000                 41
4                    7000                 41
5                    2000                 41
```

Comment: you are faster than me, I just finished, and saw your answer. Good one

Comment: Doing a quick search on this table(`master..spt_values`) shows a lot of links not recommending to use this table, since it is a legacy and undocumented table. Hence, I'm not saying your answer is wrong, but maybe creating your own table for splitting values would be better since you can never know when this table will become deprecated. *(Just my 2 cents).* Anyway, I +1ed for bringing up some new stuff about SQL Server

Comment: @Radu I agree. Using a cte with 10 values and a couple cross joins will generate a nice tally table with zero reads. That however is kind of picky for answer as solid as this one.

Comment: @SeanLange Not saying that this is not a solid answer, not saying that at all. Especially the part after the `CTE` is purely elegant. I just wanted to bring into attention other opinions.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - but note that I'm being careful not to use the *values* within that table. I'm purely using it as a table that has plenty of rows. I'll add a note to this effect

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ok, thanks for that additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared following SELECT statement using [SQL CTE expression](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) and [SQL numbers table](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-tsql-cte-numbers-table.aspx) function

```
declare @divisor int = 7000
;with CTE as (
select 
    Total, 
    [Group],
    @divisor divisor,
    (Total / @divisor) quotient,
    (Total % @divisor) reminder
from t
), NT as (
    SELECT i FROM dbo.NumbersTable(1, (select max(quotient) from CTE) ,1)
)
select
    case when i = 0 then reminder else divisor end as Total,
    [Group]
from (

    select * 
    from CTE, NT
    where quotient >= i

    union all

    select *, 0 as i
    from CTE
    where reminder >= 0

) t
order by [Group], i desc
```